Does $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_n(x_i) \to \frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_\Omega f$ if $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$?
I have a sequence $f_n \to f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ on a bounded domain $\Omega$. Define the operator $$R_n(g) := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i)$$ where $x_1, ..., x_n$ are independent and uniformly distributed samples taken from $\Omega$. We know that $R_n(g) \to \frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_\Omega g$.
My question is, does $R_n(f_n) \to \frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_\Omega f$ in some sense?  I also know that $f_n, f \in C^0(\bar\Omega)$ (and can if needed assume the convergence is in $L^\infty$ too).

@SangchulLee Yes sorry, I forgot the measure

@geetha290krm They are also continuous as written in the post

I am skeptical about the pointwise convergence of $R_n(f_n)$. I have an idea for constructing a counter-example, although I haven't really pushed this direction hard enough.
On the other hand, $L^2$-convergence is not hard to prove: Let $X, X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be IID random variable uniformly distributed on $\Omega$. Also, write $R_n(f_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f_n(X_k) $. Then
\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{E}\left[ \left( R_n(f_n) - \mathbf{E}[f(X)] \right)^2 \right] \\
&= \mathbf{Var}(R_n(f_n))
+ \mathbf{E}[f_n(X) - f(X)]^2 \tag{1} \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\mathbf{Var}(f_n(X))
+ \mathbf{E}[f_n(X) - f(X)]^2 \\
&\leq \frac{1}{n}\mathbf{E}[f_n(X)^2]
+ \mathbf{E}\left[ (f_n(X) - f(X))^2 \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{|\Omega|^2} \left( \frac{1}{n} \|f_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + \| f_n - f \|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \right).
\end{align*}

$\text{(1)}$ : Here we utilized the general fact that $\mathbf{E}[(Y - a)^2] = \mathbf{Var}(Y) + (\mathbf{E}[Y] - a)^2 $ for any square-integrable random variable $Y$ and for any constant $a$.

Now by the assumption that $f_n \to f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, this bound converge to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. (Here, note that the norm of a convergent sequence is bounded. This implies $\sup_{n\geq 1}\|f_n\|_{L^2} < \infty$.)
Consequently, $R_n(f_n)$ converges to $\mathbf{E}[f(X)] = \frac{1}{|\Omega|} \int_{\Omega} f$ in $L^2(\mathbf{P})$.

Thank you. Would you mind explaining what you mean by the convergence in $L^2(\mathbf{P})$?

@C_Al, Given a probability space $(\mathcal{S},\mathcal{F},\mathbf{P})$, the sequence of random variables $(Y_n)$ converges to the random variable $Y$ in $L^2(\mathbf{P})$ if $\mathbf{E}[|Y_n-Y|^2]\to0$. This is precisely the $L^2$-convergence for the measurable functions defined on the probability space $(\mathcal{S},\mathcal{F},\mathbf{P})$.

Ok I see. Btw I think the result is true (pointwise) if we assume $f_n \to f$ in the sup norm
